# Ask Excel to execute C# code

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel, dll

Is it possible to ask Excel to start a C# method?
How would you implement such a call in Excel?

(i.e. instead of programming in VB, I would like to program in C#)

I can imagine using a VB-macro to start a C# application in the background but maybe you know a nicer way?

For example, the C#-code shall be executed upon a click in a particular Excel cell.

Comment: Could you explain what you're doing and hoping to ultimately accomplish? It sounds like you're trying to do something super hack-y. We might be able to suggest a better way if we had some context.

Comment: Yes, I can explain a bit more in detail what I try to accomplish: Ultimately, a C# application with a nice GUI will do the entire job that eventually needs to be done. This (final) C#-application will have to deal with several Excel-Files. It will open the Excel-Files, do some **constraint-Checks** on Worksheets of several of these Excel-Files and **regroup some of its content** according to a needed order. The GUI will assist the user to do the task with the several Excel-Files. So far so good.

Comment: NOW, I try to split the work of building the GUI-architecture in several sub-tasks, in order to get my small team of programmers get going. One sub-task shall be to test the **contraint-checks** with a single Excel-File. And I do want to be able to program this task directly in C# in order to simplify the integration of that architectural sub-task in the final Appliation later on ! It is not worth programming the contraint-checks in VBA since this code won't be of any help in the final C# application. Moreover, my team knows better C# than VBA.

Answer (score 3):

Well you could open a program via VBA. This VBA script gets called by clicking on the Excel-Cell:

```
var Path = "MYPROGRAMPATH"
var Argument = "MYARGUMENT"
x = Shell("""" & Path & """ """ & Argument & """", vbNormalFocus)
```

To react on a cell change, use the following event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
'YOUR CODE
End Sub
```

Then program your C# application and let it determine the arguments.
Your program should react according to the filtered arguments.

This can be done with the [Environment.GetCommandLineArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)-Method.

```
public static void Main() 
{
   Console.WriteLine();
   //  Invoke this sample with an arbitrary set of command line arguments.
   String[] arguments = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
   Console.WriteLine("GetCommandLineArgs: {0}", String.Join(", ", arguments));
   //Handling of arguments here, switch-case, if-else, ... 
}
```

Comment: I have to admit, that this is kind of hacky. But it should do the trick.
And if it works, who cares ;-)

Comment: Thank you Janes Abou Chleih !! I will give it a try !

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on the syntax of "x = Shell(Path&Argument, vbNormalFocus)". It did not work for me right away!. If I write "x = Shell(Path, vbNormalFocus)" everything works - however the "&argument" somehow does not. I need some more help on this... Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to the VBA macro:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim pathStr As String
    Dim argumentStr As String

    pathStr = "C:/Users/.../Desktop/temp/Trial02.exe"
    argumentStr = "Any argument string"

    Call Shell("""" & pathStr & """ """ & argumentStr & """", vbNormalFocus)

End Sub
```

Comment: Oh - I guess we were same speed ;) Thanks !!